# Why doesn't my submit button submit the form?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

My form isn't always submitted when I hit the submit button.

On my form I have one submit button. When I first hit the button, the form will submit. But when there's a validation error, the error is shown. But when I fix that error and press the submit button again, the form is not submitted. This will happen if you work with 'normal' speed; if you do everything very slow, then the form will submit.

In the 'normal speed' mode I see in FireBug that there's a request to the server, but my breakpoint in the code is never hit! So I keep on the same page and nothing happens. When I click multiple times (5-10) or I wait a few seconds and then click the submit button, the submit will reach my code.

I am using MVC4 with the .NET 4.5 framework.

I hope someone can help me with this..

EDIT:

This is the code I am talking about.

My html (with razor) code:

```
<div id="content" class="boxBorder">
    <form method="post" action="/Import/ProcessStep" @(Model.UploadFiles ? "enctype=multipart/form-data" : "") id="wizardForm">
        <table id="detailsTable" width="550" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="first">Importwizard
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="ImportProgressBar">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var step in Model.StepNames)
                                { 
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="WizardProgressStep">
                                            <img src="@step.Value" class="ProgressStepImage" />
                                            <br />
                                            <span>@step.Key</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="StepTitle">
                            @Model.StepTitle
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div id="StepContent">
                            @RenderBody()
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="WizardNavigationBox">
                            @if (Model.HasPreviousButton)
                            {
                                <input type="submit" name="PreviousStep" id="PreviousStep" value="Vorige" class="button icon add" />
                            }

                            @if (Model.HasNextButton)
                            {
                                <input type="submit" name="NextStep" id="NextStep" value="Volgende" class="button icon add saveButton" />
                            }
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessStep(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        WebMediator mediator = new WebMediator();

        ViewResult newStep;
        GenericWizardViewModel viewModel;

        if (formCollection["NextStep"] != null)
        {
            ValidateStep(formCollection);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mediator.ProcessStep(formCollection);

                newStep = mediator.GetNextStep();
            }
            else
            {
                IWizardStep currentStep = mediator.GetCurrentStep();
                viewModel = mediator.CreateViewModel(currentStep);

                return this.RazorView(currentStep.StepName, viewModel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newStep = mediator.GetPreviousStep();
        }

        viewModel = newStep.Model as GenericWizardViewModel;

        return this.RazorView(newStep.ViewName, viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: What are the operations taking place prior to the submit action (ie, after user presses Submit, what happens behind-the-scenes)? Are you doing many database related operations?

Comment: Could you show us some code that working wrong?

Comment: @Afshin I Have updated my post with the code I work with

Comment: You said you have a validation in your page, this is server-side validations or client-side?

Comment: @Afshin this is server side validation. I add a `ModelError` to the `ModelState` in my controller

Comment: If you use IIS Express, try to move your project to IIS and check it again. I think it's not related to a code mistake.

Comment: I experience this phenomenon as well on my develop machine and on the deploy server. The deploy server runs IIS 7 and I am using the built-in cassini webserver from VS 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally figured it out.

All our controllers inherit from a custom `BaseController` class. This `BaseController` had an trribute with `OutputCache` on it with a duration set to 10 seconds. Removing this attribute fixed my problem.